# Detect is file is versioned

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

For example I have a hg versioned project in this path: `C:\src\sample_project`

Now, lets this project have subfolders, and lets say I'm editing a file inside this project `C:\src\sample_project\docs\index.rst`.

Having the path of this file `C:\src\sample_project\docs\index.rst` what is the easiest and most effective way to check if the file is versioned by hg, by either using Windows shell commands, hg.exe or tortoise (thg.exe)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you stated is a way, but there is a cleaner one imo. You can use:

`hg status -u` which lists all unknown (**read: not tracked**) files in your repository.

Answer (score 3):

I'll post my doubt as answer.

Command to check if file is versioned: `hg status <path>` and then if the first character in stdout of this command is `?` or `a` (from `abort: no repository found in...`) I should assume that file is not versioned.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, it made me look it up - note for Mercurial version 4.5.3, just `hg status <path/to/file>` returns nothing for me; but if I use `hg status --all <path/to/file>`, then I can get `I path/to/file` (ignored) or `C path/to/file` (clean), which is what I'd need.